French drain pipe lifting when backfill settles
I'm 80% through a French drain project & encountering a problem I never see anyone talk about.
I've got a 30ft 16"d x 12"w trench. Two 3" 4 slot coregated pipes on 4oz non-woven Geo fabric in the trench, and a big pile of 1" washed river rock.
I planned on doing pipe on fabric directly (due to necessity of having a shallow trench), but after dumping a single bucket of rock I watched the denser rocks migrate the the bottom of the trench & start lifting up the less-dense pipes which partially messed up the carefully leveling job!
Given the density differences in rock/pipe, how does this not happen with any "open" style drain?
I hope I'll be ok long term because I'll have a layer of fabric & more rocks over top... But I suspect it's going to mess up my slope during the initial backfill.
I haven't found much/any info about dealing with this phenomenon, how do pros mitigate this? Should I be staking down my pipe before filing? If so, will the punctures in the fabric reduce it's effectiveness?

My suggestion for dealing with this is to lay down a layer of stone in the bottom of the trench first and then get that all leveled out nicely before laying in any of the pipe.
Follow this up with the pipe and the filter cloth over the pipe. If you have two parallel pipes it may be best to have the filter cloth over each pipe in separate pieces so it can fold down between the pipes instead of a single strip of filter trying to bridge the gap between the runs of pipes.
Lastly install the covering rock. It can be helpful to carefully place small amounts of the rock every three to six feet (1 to 2 meters) to hold the pipe down before coming along and dumping large amounts of rocks in the trench.

Ah, the expense and extra work of using arguably the worst type of drain pipe out there.
This is much less of a problem with rigid pipes, since they are rigid. It may also be getting aggravated by "dumping a bucket" of rocks rather than placing them with a bit more care and less violence. Particularly if it's an equipment bucket rather than a 5 gallon bucket, but even the 5 gallon one is going to be rather violent if dumped from above ground level to fall into the trench on the pipe. Normal placement of stone around the actual pipe (assuming the worker gives a {bleep} about doing a good job) is via shovel with a foot on top of the pipe, until the pipe is fully covered. Then you can fill faster, with a wheelbarrow or loader bucket. Of course with corrugated, you can't actually stand on the unsupported pipe, or it will crush.
I suppose you could build something with a couple of boards on edge to sit on your drain pipes, and frame cross-pieces to hold heavy things (box of rocks will work) to keep the boards and pipes held down while you fill that section above the pipes, then you can dump the box of rocks into the trench or remove the weight and pull the boards and frame up vertically without disturbing the pipes, and mov it along the trench. Might need two of those so you can leapfrog them.

Unfortunately there is no heavy machinery involved (aside from the trencher rental). I've only dumped about 1/4 of a 5gal bucket but stopped to re-evaluate when I noticed this. I guess this is where diy pays off bc I'm not on the clock so I can take my time. I've heard about these big box store corrugated pipes that will crush under 200lbs of human standing on em, and maybe the 3" is less susceptible or I got a good one, but it's sturdy.  It sounds like there's no standard bulletproof solution so maybe I'll try the stand on it while filling technique.

Sounds like your problem is basically a bouyancy issue.  The pipe is basically air, and you're dumping much denser stone around it.  If you're simply dumping stone, I would consider placing stone by hand on both sides (a bit at a time) until the stone is above the midline of the pipe.  Anchoring the pipe may be worth it too—stick a couple pieces of rebar in so they cross over the pipe diagonally (like an X) to keep it in the middle of the trench.  You can pull the rebar once that section of pipe is secured by stone, and move it to the next section.
